# What Hash need for Signature verification?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-theory, signature

When miners verifies a transaction, they make some calculations to check its Signature by using some Hash.

What Hash is used for Sig verification in Bitcoin Core?

Comment: @Denis, the same hash that was used by transaction creator when he signed it.

Comment: @amaclin but block `miner` is not `creator` of transaction

Comment: @Denis, yes, but the process of calculating the hash is the same

Answer (score 0):

I think that the hash function used is `sha256d`, a non-standard function obtained by hashing with `sha256` twice (first hash the data, obtain 256-byte digest, then re-hash the digest).